# Installing systemfonts package from CRAN and GitHub fails

Tags: r

I recently upgraded my intel MacBook from Catalina to Monterey (Darwin release 21.1.0) I also upgraded R from 4.0.1 to 4.1.1 via home-brew.  I have reinstalled the majority of packages necessary for my work, however, ran into issues with `mapview`.  It failed to install due to an issue with a dependency - `systemfonts`. I attempted to install systemfonts directly from CRAN and after that failed from GitHub which also failed with these messages:

```
/bin/sh: I/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.1_1/lib/R/include: No such file or directory
make: [mac/FontManagerMac.o] Error 127 (ignored)
```

and

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'mac/FontManagerMac.o'
make: *** [systemfonts.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘systemfonts’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.1/site-library/systemfonts’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/85/56q39hqj2_gf31m9mbln7hhw0000gn/T//RtmpJGiNgA/file324134b404c/systemfonts_1.0.3.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this issue.  I may open an issue on GitHub r-lib/systemfonts as this may be related to some sort of incompatibility between the package and the updated OS however, thought I should start here.

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything relevant before that `include:` error? That looks as if the compilation command is missing a dash, since I'd think it should be `-I/usr/local/...`. My guess is *that* error causes the missing `.o` file, so it may be useful to have more context around the first error. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use homebrew? The homebrew version of R just doesn't work well when you need to compile source packages.  If you used an official R build for mac this will probably work just fine.

Comment: r2evans - this is the output line immediately preceding that error `I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.1_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.1/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include  -fobjc-arc -fPIC   -c mac/FontManagerMac.mm -o mac/FontManagerMac.o`

Comment: What about the line before that? Since I don't know how far back in lines to go, it might be best to include the output from `install.packages(.)` through the error.

Comment: I uninstalled the R version from homebrew and then installed the official version from CRAN as suggested by MrFlick.  R and all packages installed without error.   I did not know that "The homebrew version of R just doesn't work well when you need to compile source packages.", however, this does seem to be the case.  Thanks!

Comment: Having the same problem, looks like an issue has been opened https://github.com/r-lib/systemfonts/issues/84

Answer (score 8):

1. In the bash shell:

   sudo apt install libfontconfig1-dev
2. in RStidio

   install.packages("systemfonts", dependencies = TRUE)

Comment: Not a useful answer as OP is on macOS.

Answer (score 4):

The solution listed in the issue from @Kevin_Cazelles [linked to](https://github.com/r-lib/systemfonts/issues/84) worked on my computer. Seems like it has something to do with gcc and R's call for the compiler.

This worked for me:

```
brew reinstall gcc 
brew link --overwrite gcc
```

and then this in R-studio terminal

```
withr::with_makevars(c(OBJCXX = "gcc"), install.packages('systemfonts'))
```